# C# EF 3.x FromSqlRaw on server view

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, .net-core

Im not sure what im doing wrong. But when im using FromSqlRaw i seem "never" to get the result when the view contain a huge amount of data.

I have a local SQL Server that has a view to a database on a Linked Server. The view contains a query to filter from 100.000 entries to around 30.000.

In my code

```
builder.Entity<PpsDashboard.Models.Server.BigDataSetData>().HasNoKey();
builder.Entity<PpsDashboard.Models.Server.SmallDataSetData>().HasNoKey();
```

i have the dbSets in the context:

```
public DbSet<xxx> BigDataSetData
{
    get;
    set;
}
    
public DbSet<xxx> SmallDataSetData
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

And Models for both.

When running the three lines below line 1 and 2 works, but the one fetching data for the big dataset never returns an error or finish - the small database contains 10 entries:

```
var items = context.SmallDataSetData.AsQueryable();
var items2 = context.SmallDataSetData.FromSqlRaw("Select TOP 2 * from [dbo].[smallDataBase] where name like 'thomas'").ToList();
var books = context.BigDataSetData.FromSqlRaw("Select TOP 2 * from [dbo].[bigDataBase] where name like 'thomas'").ToList();
```

When running FromSqlRaw will it invoke the entire call to the view or just quire the needed data? The Linked Server is physical located another place in the world on another continent so there are quiet a bit of latency getting data in general.

/Thomas

Comment: Did this query `Select TOP 2 * from [dbo].[bigDataBase] where name like 'thomas'` success in SSMS tool?

Comment: Yes im starting to think it might be some access issues due to linked servers, but still not sure

Answer (score 0):

The following could help you to understand the EF background SQL Server Query execution that could lead you to the root cause :
use some kind of SQL server profiler (SQL Server built-in profiler) , or new Azure data studio profiler.